# CosmosDB: Can a key be a duplicated? Key: Value (documentDB/SqlAPi)

Tags: json, azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

CosmosDB SQL API. Does it need a key as unique? Is the optimization or performance varies when the uniqueness changes?

Comment: The need for unique key (`id`) is well-documented. Not sure I understand your question...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're referring to, regarding optimization or performance, but... within a Partition (or with a single-partition 10gb collection), every `id` must be unique. You cannot insert data otherwise. And a point-read function takes the document's `id` (along with partition id, if a partitioned collection) as parameters, returning a single document.

If you needed a key with non-unique values, you'd need to create your own property. You could then query on that property having a value, and return the set of documents with that matching value.